# Kentico Google Analytics page view

Tags: google-analytics, kentico

I'm looking at the GA traffic and I'm seeing page views for pages like this:    /cms/getdoc/2d22c1db-ae83...angobjectlifetime=request

Is this page used when a user is viewing a document (PDF, Word, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary. It could be any page within the content tree (including files). The cms prefix means it requires authentication (it's usually within the administration interface) and the getdoc handler means the url is permanent one (uses the GUID that follows), so you always get this page/file no matter where in the content tree it is (after you move it for example)

Comment: Ok thanks. We are using windows auth, and i'm working on filter out office traffic. I'll keep an eye out and worst case drop these with another filter.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics records anything hit to your website which is used to access either to access a legitimate page or used to access a resource on your website. You should use filters during report to filter out this data.

Comment: I will be. I just figured out what the page is, just verifying it now before i create a filter.

thanks!